# (Topological) Entropy and Perron-Frobenius

Tags: dynamical-systems, entropy

If we have a subshift $X$ on which we have the left-shift $\sigma$, we can look at the adjacency matrix $A$ of $X$ and in case $A$ is non-negative, Perron-Frobenius tells us that the entropy $h(X)$ is given by $\log\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$.

Are there other similar results where we can use the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue to express the entropy in case we have an adjacent matrix but are not considering the left-shift but some other dynamics?